# Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to repair a site that has a problem when entering the username and password on wp-login.php page.
[image]

My friend who has tried to solve it did not found any error in server error logs and debugging error and nothing there also. He even thought that the server is on gigabit link so I think that is excluded as a reason also.

I have transferred the files on my computer to try to detect the problem locally on my computer in a local environment. I am using xampp and VS code.

In vsc i have opened wp-login.php and I have a small error but I saw that is got something to do with PHP intelephense plugin on VSC and the solution could be just by updating it. But the problem is that it is already updated to the newest version

[image]

I would be appreciative if someone could give me some pointers on how to detect this problem and where to start looking. I would like to detect the problem locally and then change the file that is corrupted.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried a Different Browser usually fixes it for me?

Comment: Yes, on Internet explorer & Edge. Does not work.

Comment: Can u give firefox or chrome a try for me?

Comment: Yes i forgot to say chrome, i use it on default

Comment: Usually what we do is, If this happens we Change browsers if that doesnt work we clear Cookies and History wich almost always sorts it.Also Remember to clear IE's Cookies

Comment: Yes but the thing is that this wp site was live and had that problem so when anyone who tried to login and solve this problem would like to enter dashboard he would be blocked by this error. So i am trying to figure out what happened. Some guys in 2017. built this web and got this error and the owner is looking for someone to resolve this issue. I was wondering if this was set on purpose (did not payed or something) , any suggestion will be of help.

Comment: I’d start by checking what cookies the server actually tries to set in the response. Maybe the domain / path parameters are off, so that the browser doesn’t accept it for the domain & path WP is actually running under.

Answer (score 0):

The only a few major reasons for getting this error are:

- Security or caching plugins
- Migration to another host / Change of server address/IP
- Browser issue

Try first to purge your browser cookies. This works in 90% of all cases where you get that cookie error.

If you still get that error to add the line below into your wp-config.php

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

I have written a few more in detail instructions on how to solve it but I think you will be good by following the steps above.

Source: https://wp-staging.com/how-to-fix-the-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser/

Answer (score -1):

please check all theme files(mainly functions.php) and remove extra line or space at the end then it will resolve